# Brand specific web.config sections automation

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am doing some research on how to make web.config dynamic per environment and brand. We have web.config different for different environments and brands.

Right now we make copy of it store a separate files and finally pick it manually and deploy.

I am finding various arcticles to do this and one the below has one solution.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx

I don't want any code or anything like but need some references if there are any other best industry practices

Answer (score 1):

See   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx for web.config transformations. Same concept. You have a base config file and then have specific nested config  files per environment, brand or both. Depending how you deploy your application can affect how many web.config you have.  In newer visual studio you cannpreview the changes as well by clicking on the nested web.config in solution explorer

App.config transformations aren't supported out of the box but with some msbuild events that's how wendo these ones